# ExtJs - Debugging Methods

Tags: javascript, extjs

ExtJs/Sencha newbie here. Trying to debug something that does not work in a large system. There is a URL, when clicked, supposed to do something. How do I know where its click event binding is done? I see no clues in Firebug. The handler could have been bound by its class/id/type/name/ etc. What tools are useful. Tried Dynatrace, not very helpful.

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an add-on that adds ExtJS intelligence to Firebug:

http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/

You can use that add-on to get a handle to the ExtJS component. An alternative is looking in the DOM inspector to find out the component id (starts with 'ext-') and then using Ext.getCmp() passing in the component id to get the handle to the component.

Once you have a handle to the component, you can use the ExtJS API to find out whether there is a click listener on the component: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-hasListener